# jQuery how to hide parent Div based on checked state of child

Tags: jquery

I have the following approximate HTML:

```
<div class="productDiv"><div class="someClass><div><input type="checkbox" class="product"/></div></div></div>
<div class="productDiv"><div class="someClass><div><input type="checkbox" class="product"/></div></div></div>
etc.
```

I am trying to toggle view between all products and only selected products. The view is the parent div, and the checked product checkbox is a few div's deep. What's the best way to show the parent based on a child's checked state, please?

here's my Jquery which is not working.

```
$('.productDiv').hide().filter('.product:input:checked').show();
```

Thanks!

Comment: missing closing quote in your question.. check it please. `"productDiv"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve what you want by using the following jquery:

```
$('.productDiv').hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('input.product:checked').length > 0;
}).show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/PNySd/

Answer (score 1):

Select all checked inputs and then go up the dom tree to their parent:

```
$('.productDiv').hide();
$('.product:input:checked').parents('.productDiv').show();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as well but was less close to my original approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create the change event, then trigger the change event:

```
$(".product").change(function() {
    this.checked ? $(this).parents(".productDiv").show() : $(this).parents(".productDiv").hide();
}).change();
```

Comment: Change the second `?` for `:`

Comment: @MG_Bautista -- Fixed, first answer for the morning, need to settle in yet

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selector with the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) action.
Like that:

```
$('.product').next().hide();
$('.product').change(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Here is the full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2eKJ/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox .product').each(function(){
    if(!($(this).is(':checked'))){
         $(this).closest('.productDiv').hide();
    }
});
```